# Heroku deploy com bower-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bower

Tenho a `gem 'bower-rails'` instalada em minha aplicação mas ao efetuar o deploy tenho o seguinte erro:

Adicionei a `gem rails_12factor`

Estou usando o *buildpack*:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

Está retornando o seguinte erro

```
remote:        Bundle complete! 37 Gemfile dependencies, 88 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (121.61s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Bower not found! You can install Bower using Node and npm:
remote:        $ npm install bower -g
remote:        For more info see http://bower.io/
remote:        Bower not found! You can install Bower using Node and npm:
remote:        $ npm install bower -g
remote:        For more info see http://bower.io/
remote:        Bower not found! You can install Bower using Node and npm:
remote:        $ npm install bower -g
remote:        For more info see http://bower.io/
remote:        I, [2015-05-22T15:10:45.780939 #1511]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_4a3496582f01151aa98229107df764c1/public/assets/about-circles-59d0b7d256daae90abc3db6014a27a1017f6f3eea84940e680aeadcee6a9f3ba.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-05-22T15:10:45.801573 #1511]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_4a3496582f01151aa98229107df764c1/public/assets/imac-984a728f1d9fe0dc438aab4016ad8a8e56f760f40517770dd1e711cb62fe64a1.jpg
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'gmaps-waypoints.js/index.js' with type 'application/javascript'
remote:        /tmp/build_4a3496582f01151aa98229107df764c1/vendor/assets/javascripts/vendors.js:1
```

O que poderia ser:

Comment: Você já instalou a gem `rails_12factor?`

Comment: Está instalada no **group :production**. Veja o log de instalação: `remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3`

Comment: Configurou algum buildpack personalizado?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, mas quando instalei a `rails_12factor` e alterei o buildpack o problema resolveu.

Comment: Mas estou usando o buildpack do próprio heroku. Qual você usou?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24030/discussion-between-jpklzm-and-daniel).

Comment: Essa pergunta foi resolvida? Tive um problema parecido e optei por usar o rails-assets! Sinceramente tentei de tudo ahahahahha!

Comment: Ele disse para eu tentar colocar o **bower** no **package.json** mas ainda não tive tempo de testar. Tenta lá se der certo me avisa também.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que os assets não estão sendo encontrados.
tenta adicionar no seu config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components","assets","fonts")
config.assets.precompile << %r(.*.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$)
```

Em todo caso,
criei esse repositorio no github mostrando utilização da gem bower-rails.
O deploy no heroku rolou sem problemas.
[receta-tutorial-angular](https://github.com/amalrik/receta)

que por sua vez copiei desse tutorial:
[angular-rails-tutorial](http://angular-rails.com/bootstrap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Estou com o mesmo problema mas a solução apresentada pelo colega @amalrik não resolve o problema. Pois no caso da receita que ele apresenta em https://github.com/amalrik/receta ele adiciona as libs js ao git.

O interessante seria conseguir fazer o Heroku rodar um `bower install` antes do `rake assets:precompile`.

Consegui resolver isso setando para usar os seguinte buildpack https://github.com/qnyp/heroku-buildpack-ruby-bower.git#run-bower